# border-image: linear-gradient behavior on Safari (iOS) not as expected

Tags: css

I've created a menu where the menu-items are underlined for a little bit (see picture):

[image: Screenshot]

It is showing as expected on all screen sizes and in differtent browsers. The only problem I have is that it is not showing correctly on Safari on iOS (see picture 2):

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```css
.list-item {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    -o-border-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#cbd2d9,#cbd2d9 40px,transparent 41px,transparent);
    border-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#cbd2d9,#cbd2d9 40px,transparent 41px,transparent);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    padding-left:0px;
}
.list-item-link {
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list-unstyled row ul-pages' data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
        <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link" target="_blank">Bibliotheek</a></h3></li>
    <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Cultuur</a></h3></li>
    <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Erfgoed</a></h3></li><li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Evenementen</a></h3></li>
    <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Jeugd</a></h3></li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a simple gradient as background:

```css
.list-item {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(#cbd2d9 0 0) bottom left/40px 1px no-repeat;
}
.list-item-link {
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class='list-unstyled row ul-pages' data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
        <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link" target="_blank">Bibliotheek</a></h3></li>
    <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Cultuur</a></h3></li>
    <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Erfgoed</a></h3></li><li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Evenementen</a></h3></li>
    <li class="list-item col-md-4"><h3><a href="#" class="list-item-link">Jeugd</a></h3></li>
</ul>
```